# save data with preferences in libGDX

Tags: java, libgdx

In My game project, I want to save some data of levels like coins, gams, ... etc with preferences interface.

I supposed In My Question here the data is the level number only.
........................................................................

1) If the player finish the level_1, this code called to save `LEVEL_NUM_`.

```
preferences.putInteger("LEVEL_NUM_", getLevelNum());
preferences.flush();
```

The `.prefs`'s file :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    <!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">
    <properties>
    <entry key="LEVEL_NUM_">1</entry>
    <entry key="SCORE_">3225</entry>
    </properties>
```

2) If the player finish the level_2, this code called again to save `LEVEL_NUM_`.

```
preferences.putInteger("LEVEL_NUM_", getLevelNum());
preferences.flush();
```

The preferences update the data i.e. replace the `LEVEL_NUM_`'s data with a new `LEVEL_NUM_`'s data.

The NEW `.prefs`'s file :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    <!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">
    <properties>
    <entry key="LEVEL_NUM_">2</entry>
    <entry key="SCORE_">5995</entry>
    </properties>
```

I want to add the data (like stack) NOT replace the data. What I do ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

all you need is to keep your levels in some collection (like Array<>) and then save this collection to Preferences. You will need to cast this collection to String (there's no **putArray()** function or something like this) and the best idea is to jsonify it.

**JSON** is a file format (something like xml but much lighter) with good support from libgdx side. The code to achieve your goal is something like:

```
    FloatArray levels = new FloatArray();
    levels.add(5993);
    levels.add(5995);

    ...

    Preferences p = Gdx.app.getPreferences("SETTINGS");

    Json json = new Json();

    String levelsJson = json.toJson(FloatArray.class, levels);

    p.putString("levels", levelsJson);
```

now you've got you levels collection saved and all you have to do to get it back is:

```
    FloatArray levels = json.fromJson(FloatArray.class, p.getString("levels");
```

Regards,
Michał

Comment: Perfect Answer. THANX MIichal.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution would be to store the score of each level in it's own Key/Value pair, where the Key is the level and the value is the score:

```
preferences.putInteger("LEVEL_NUM_" + getLevelNum(), getScore());
prefernces.flush();
```

And the preferences would look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">
<properties>
   <entry key="LEVEL_NUM_1">3225</entry>
   <entry key="LEVEL_NUM_2">5995</entry>
</properties>
```

Comment: Really Nice Solution. Thanx