# ilbgdx JSON saving array into preferences

Tags: android, json, libgdx

How to save array into JSON and then make that JSON into string and save it into preferences Android. And after that be able to load string from preferences into JSON and then take the array. Since there are no JSONarrays in libgdx

Comment: Detailed instructions for writing the array to a Json string here: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Reading-%26-writing-JSON  Then use preferences to save and load the string: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Preferences

Comment: Hi, take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32239499/save-data-with-preferences-in-libgdx/32240906#32240906) - I have described there how to deal with *FloatArray* - maybe it will be helpful (if not describe exactly what to do maybe I will be able to help)

Comment: By your comments I see you are actually looking for a library to handle json, not a way to save json. which is provided in the answers. Please try to formulate your question better to let us know what you really need. Also provide a code sample showing you at least tried something yourself.

Answer (score 2):

i think,

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json;
```

and,

```
Json json = new Json();
```

create function to get libgdx preferences.

```
private Preferences getPreferences() {
   return Gdx.app.getPreferences(PREFERENCES_NAME);
}
```

then, convert your array into string,

```
String str = json.toJson(yourArray);
```

last, pass the string into libgdx preferences using `putString()`

```
getPreferences().putString(ARRAY_JSON_PREFERENCES, str);
getPreferences().flush();
```

to get the array from the preferences.

```
String theArrayString = getPreferences().getString(ARRAY_JSON_PREFERENCES,json.toJson(defaultArray));
```

next, to build the theArrayString into array

```
int[] yourBuidArray = json.fromJson(int[].class, theArrayString);
```

or

```
String[] yourBuidArray = json.fromJson(String[].class, theArrayString);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you can do with libgdx, but if you are free to use external libs, you should use Gson.
You serialize your object in json String with Gson, and then save it in preferences. Later, you make the "reverse".

```
private static String listToJson(List<?> list){
    return new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create().toJson(list);
}
```

Then :

```
JSONObject myJson = new JSONObject(stringFromMyPreferences);
```

Comment: I don't have even JSonArray. That's why I need help